# Fetching data by renderer in ag-grid using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am doing a project in ag-grid and using renderer to render selected gender from it. But, I am not able to fetch the data back. Actually, I have to get the value selected in the dropdown, I tried a lot but I am not able to get it. Please can someone help me with this? At least can I get a hint

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            columnDefs: [
                { headerName: "Id", field: "Id", width: 120, checkboxSelection: true, sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true, resizable: true },
                { headerName: "Name", field: "Name", width: 140, sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true, resizable: true },
                { headerName: "Email", field: "Email", width: 200, sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true, resizable: true },
                { headerName: "Gender", field: "Gender", cellRenderer: 'genderRenderer', cellRendererParams: { onGenderChange: this.onGenderChange }, width: 140, sortable: true, filter: true, resizable: true },
                { headerName: "DOB", field: "DOB", cellRenderer: 'dateRenderer', cellRendererParams: { onDateChange: this.onDateChange }, width: 160, sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true, resizable: true },
                { headerName: "Country", field: "Country", cellRenderer: 'countryRenderer', cellRendererParams: { onCountryChange: this.onCountryChange }, width: 140, sortable: true, filter: true, resizable: true },
                { headerName: "City", field: "City", cellRenderer: 'cityRenderer', cellRendererParams: { onCityChange: this.onCityChange }, width: 140, sortable: true, filter: true, resizable: true },
                { headerName: " ", field: "Delete", cellRenderer: 'deleteRenderer' }
            ],
            rowData: [
                { 'Id': '1', 'Name': "kishor", 'Email': "kishor@gmail.com", 'Gender': "", 'DOB': "", 'Country': "", 'City': "" },

            ],
            suppressAggFuncInHeader: true,

            frameworkComponents: {
                genderRenderer: GenderRenderer,
        }
        this.onGenderChange = this.onGenderChange.bind(this)
    }
    onGenderChange = (setGender) => {
        console.log("Gender Change", setGender)
    }
```

GenderRenderer.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function GenderRenderer(props) {
    const[gender, setGender] = useState(props.value);

    const onGenderChange = (event) => {
        props.onGenderChange(event.target.value);
        setGender(event.target.value);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <select name="select" value={gender} onChange={onGenderChange}>
                <option value="male"> Male </option>
                <option value="female"> Female </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GenderRenderer;
```

Comment: Is it a typo or your real code? 

`frameworkComponents: {
                genderRenderer: GenderRenderer,
 }`
you didn't close this.state

Comment: it is a part of the original code. In original code i have closed it @Elisey

Comment: What are you getting from `console.log("Gender Change", setGender)` ?

Comment: I am getting the value that I have selected i.e. if I select female then I get Gender Change Female